# How do I make rails errors in Capybara show up in rspec features?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I'm using capybara to run my rspec features. The issue is that when an error occurs in the rails stack while running the spec, the error doesn't "pass through" to rspec and cause the test to fail. The error page is generated and checked by rspec.

So, I don't get an immediate failure with an error on my specs. I only get an error when I look for content, or try to fill in a field, that doesn't appear on the error page.

This is not what I want. I want errors encountered in the rails stack (controller, views, etc.) to cause rspec to fail immediately.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Capybara is capable of raising server errors as failures on your tests, provided it's hooking into Rails correctly (see: [the last bullet point on the "Gotchas" section of the README](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#gotchas)).

Make sure that you:

- Are running your Capybara tests in your Rails environment
- Have `require 'capybara/rails'` in your `spec_helper.rb` or `rails_helper.rb` file
- Do not need your actual server running in order to run the tests (if you do, this is a symptom that your setup is incorrect).
- Are visiting relative, not absolute, URLs in your tests (e.g. `visit 'http://localhost:3000/mypage` is wrong, `visit '/mypage'` is right).

If the above are all true, and you're still seeing the behavior, something else is likely wrong with your setup. Try changing your driver back to the default (Rack::Test) and see if the issue persists.

Edit: as explained in the comments below, the issue here was that the `better_errors` gem was loading in the test environment, which rescued the error and displayed the pretty error page before Capybara and Rspec got a chance to see the error. Moving it to the `development`-only group in the Gemfile fixed the issue. [This thread](https://forum.upcase.com/t/rspec-capybara-not-showing-rails-errors/1872/6) held the answer.

Comment: Everything in the bullet points you provided checks out ok. How do I change the driver back to default? Just remove the `require capybara/rails` line?

Comment: If you aren't using a specific driver, it'd already be using the default one. In which case, it may be worth a shot to try a different driver (see https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#selecting-the-driver).

Comment: As another question, what webserver are you using? If you're using, say, thin, and it's in your Gemfile to always be loaded, you may be hitting an error like described in https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/329.

Comment: I'm not using thin or anything else different from the default.

Comment: When you say "The error page is generated and checked by rspec", do you mean the red-and-white default error page of Rails (with the stack trace, etc), or your app's error page? If the latter, your app may be rescuing the error and thus not letting Capybara handle it.

Comment: I mean that instead of rspec stopping the spec due to the error condition, the actual error page is rendered, and rspec won't fail unless I look for specific content on the error page. I'm not really seeing anywhere that I'm specifically rescuing the error.

Comment: You might check out the solutions in this thread: https://forum.upcase.com/t/rspec-capybara-not-showing-rails-errors/1872/6

Comment: That was it! I had better_errors at the root of my Gemfile, moved it to just development, and everything works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Create a test case for your controller / view and test it before doing any integration tests.

That's the right way to do it :

- unit testing for methods
- functional testing for controllers / views
- integration tests then

Comment: Sorry, but this isn't what I'm asking about. We've all got our own opinions on testing, but I'm just looking for a technical detail here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following `capybara` method to force the scenario to fail.

```
fail(msg = "Error. Check log for details.")
```

Comment: I'm looking for a long-term solution, not a piece of code I'd have to add to every test.